# Cannot connect to ethereum private network

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

When I do `/Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOs/Mist --rpc /Users/mushahid/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc`​ I get connected to Ropsten instead of my private network.